# Change default so Jupyter Notebook doesn't show heading prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Does anyone know how to make it so that Jupyter Notebook doesn't show me this prompt every time I select `Heading` option?  I've created a jupyter_notebook_config.py file, but I didn't see an option to turn it off.  I like to use headings often to break up my code and keep better documentation, but I find it annoying to constantly click OK every time.

[image]

Comment: Select markdown in the dropdown menu instead of heading. They're the same thing and the first one doesn't ask you to press Ok.

Answer (score 3):

The warning is not that headings are gone, it is that heading *cells* don't exist anymore. All text cells are markdown now, and you create headings by prefixing the line with a number of `#` symbols to indicate the heading level. When you see this dialog, it is not creating a heading cell; it is creating a markdown cell with the right number of `#` characters.

The way to avoid the warning is to create markdown cells and add the `#` characters yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To not get a prompt you can just:

1. enter your text in the cell
2. hit esc to enter command mode
3. press 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 keys for getting a heading(1-6) respectively
4. simultaneously press (shift + return/enter)